# mp4s and jogs on micro sd that are black

Tags: video, vlc, mp4

I took a number of videos and photos with my Canon on a "generic" micro sd card.  Many of them show up and work fine but there are some files that seem to be corrupt.  They won't show in the finder and won't open in any apps.

If I play the mp4s in VLC it shows the bar moving but no picture or sound. These files appear to have information.  For example if I "get info" on the file is shows the size of the file, date time and duration.

If I ask for media information in VLC it shows all the information - framerate, channels, resolution, bitrate... but it won't play.

Is there anything that I can do to get these videos to play?

Comment: Have you verified that these videos can actually play? That they are not actually corrupt?

Comment: I believe they are corrupt.  They wouldn't play back on my Canon and will not upload to any application.